# Trouble using Sympy to integrate

Tags: python, math, sympy, physics, symbolic-integration

So I've been using Sympy as a tool for integration in python. Usually I have no problem but this time it isn't giving me a very useful answer.

```
from sympy import *
psi, x, a = symbols('psi, x, a') #Where a is a real constant 
def psi(x):
    return 1./(x**2 + a**2)
I = integrate(psi(x)**2 ,(x,-oo,oo))  #No complex conjugate 
print I
```

a is supposed to be a real constant and the solution should equal one, its a wave function and I need to find a. Anyone who could help me to find a better way on to how to integrate this would be appreciated.

The answer for this integration should be:
0.5*pi* (1./a**2)**1.5

Comment: This is a right answer `0.5*pi/a**3` which is the same as what you get `0.5*pi* (1./a**2)**1.5`

Comment: The answer I'm getting is:

Comment: Piecewise((0.5*pi/a**3, Or(Abs(periodic_argument(polar_lift(a)**(-2), oo)) < pi, And(Abs(periodic_argument(polar_lift(a)**(-2), oo)) != -pi, Abs(periodic_argument(polar_lift(a)**(-2), oo)) != pi, Abs(periodic_argument(polar_lift(a)**(-2), oo)) < pi, a**(-2) != 0))), (Integral(1.0/(a**2 + x**2)**2, (x, -oo, oo)), True))

Comment: The solution `sympy` gives you is correct. In the general case, `a` could also be equal to zero, in which case the integrand has a pole at `x == 0` and must be handled using special functions and analytic continuation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use assumption(`positive=True`) depending on your variable to simplify. Here is the example.

```
from sympy import *
psi, x, a = symbols('psi, x, a',positive=True) #Where a is a real constant 
def psi(x):
    return 1./(x**2 + a**2)
I = integrate(psi(x)**2 ,(x,-oo,oo))  #No complex conjugate 
print I
```

The answer would be `0.5*pi/a**3` which is  the right answer.

Comment: @AlwaysStuck I like python very much but I still have to rely on mathematica for most of my symbolic calculations. Hopefully one day `simpy` can take over.